# Verify SSH authentication with Bash Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, python, authentication

I need to test SSH authentication on a few servers. Let say the IP Addresses of those servers are saved in `ip.txt` file

I've written similar script in Python using `paramiko` and `netmiko` module.

The problem now I've to test it from a server where there is no Python3 or Internet connection.

Therefore, installation of 3rd party tools or Python modules are not an option here.

`expect`, `sshpass` are also not available.

The only thing available is bash script. Is it possible to do this on Bash alone? How do I pass `password` to the ssh?

Answer (score 1):

Try `SSH_ASKPASS`

man ssh

> ...
>
> SSH_ASKPASS
>
> If ssh needs a passphrase, it will read the
> passphrase from the current terminal if it was run from a terminal.
> If ssh does not have a
> terminal associated with it but DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS are set, it will execute the program specified by
> SSH_ASKPASS and open an X11
> window to read the passphrase.  This is particularly useful when calling ssh from a .xsession or related
> script.  (Note that on some
> machines it may be necessary to redirect the input from /dev/null to make this work.)
>
> ...

```
$ cat echoPass
echo passwordHere

$ cat sshSession
export SSH_ASKPASS='~/echoPass'
setsid ssh user@server

$./sshSession
user@server:~$ whoami
user
user@server:~$
```